# Radio input default check revered

Tags: html, radio-button

I have this radiobutton group created from MVC:

```
<div class="editor-field">
  <input checked="True" id="1" name="CopyOrCut" type="radio" value="1" /> Copy
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  <input checked="False" id="2" name="CopyOrCut" type="radio" value="2" /> Cut
</div>
```

But the radio with value of 2 "CUT", is the one that is prechecked. Have I doen something wrong? I've not posted the MVC code because this is a html issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To check a checkbox set the `checked` attribute to `checked`.  If you do not wish to check a checkbox do not specify any `checked` attribute.

```
<div class="editor-field">
  <input checked="checked" id="1" name="CopyOrCut" type="radio" value="1" /> Copy
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  <input id="2" name="CopyOrCut" type="radio" value="2" /> Cut
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i realised this was because the only keyword required is checked.

Comment: @DavidB Your welcome, hope this helped.  I wish someone would explain the downvote though.

Comment: It wasn't me. I didnt upvote though because I felt your answer lacked a helpful explanation of the code (though in this case its obvious). I will accpet however when the limiot is passed.

Comment: @DavidB I wasn't inferring it was you.  I just didn't want to post two comments, (looks like that failed).  I would just be interested to see what the issue someone felt was with this markup.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, it would be better to simply not have the checked field even mentioned in the second input or simply make it `checked=""`. Using True and False is not a proper way of defining checked. For more information look here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked there first!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a very simple way to do this, just use this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
 <input id="1" name="CopyOrCut" type="radio" value="1" checked> Copy
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
 <input id="2" name="CopyOrCut" type="radio" value="2" > Cut
</div>
```